# Unable to load dynamic PHP extension on Cygwin

Tags: php, cygwin

I have successfully compiled PHP 5.4.9 on Cygwin, but now I am unable to dynamically load MongoDB extension. That's the PHP CLI output:

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.dll' - No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

However, it is definitely there:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Linker None 204288 Dec 12 02:12 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.dll
```

The DLL file has been downloaded from official MongoDB GitHub repo. It is actually renamed php_mongo-1.3.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll.
The curious moment: when I try to substitute it with x86_64 version (which my OS version) - it says that DLL has wrong exec format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downlaoded the extension it is built to be run as native windows dll with PHP compiled using Visual Studio. A PHP compiled using cyhwin-gcc can't use it.

Either compile the extension yourself into an cygwin .so or use a PHP compiled using visual studio (the later is prefered)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, at first I've tried to compile the extension, as well - but it produced the `.a` file, which is not suitable. Do you know how to force the compiler to produce `.so` instead? If there's no way - I'll try to re-compile PHP in VC.

Comment: I have found the workaround - just compiled the extension statically, using this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.static.php